# How to fix Macports configuration error like this?

Tags: macos, macports

When running

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

I got

```
...
--->    tig @0.18_0
--->    lynx @2.8.7rel.1_1+ssl
--->    lame @3.99.5_0
--->    gettext @0.18.2.1_0+universal
--->    libedit @20121213-3.0_0+universal
--->    python27 @2.7.5_0+universal
--->    texlive-bin @2012_10+motif+x11
Warning: Deactivate forced.  Proceeding despite dependencies.
--->  Cleaning ncurses
--->  Uninstalling ncurses @5.9_2+universal
--->  Cleaning ncurses
--->  Installing ncurses @5.9_2+universal
--->  Activating ncurses @5.9_2+universal
--->  Cleaning ncurses
--->  Computing dependencies for gettext
--->  Configuring gettext
Error: org.macports.configure for port gettext returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port gettext for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_svn.macports.org_trunk_dports_devel_gettext/gettext/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What does `/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_svn.macports.org_trunk_dports_devel_gettext/gettext/main.log` say?

Comment: The complete content of the file is [this](http://pastebin.com/CtZX4TAQ).